# What is the ancient Greek word for apprenticeship?

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek

I'm looking for an ancient Greek word that denotes a trainee craftsman's regime of study under a master, I found the word μαθητεία but I'm unsure if that is a word in ancient Greek or only in modern Greek. Could someone let me know if it is or point me to a better word if it isn't please?

Comment: In the Christian bible, you'll often see this relationship expressed with the Aramaic loan words ῥαββί and ῥαββονί. Rabbi just meant "master," and it was the customary way for an apprentice to address the person who had accepted them as an apprentice. Rabboni is an obsequious form meaning "great master."

Comment: Does "eromenos" count? IIRC there was sort of a tradition of them being taught "how to be a man", right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eromenos Posting as a comment instead of an answer because I'm not an expert and I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [μαθητεία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=maqhtei/a) is a word that would certainly be understood in this context, though in practice it was usual to talk about someone *being a [μαθητής](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=maqhth/s)* to someone rather than about μαθητεία in the abstract. This applies not just in the context of manual craftsmanship but for any τέχνη, including e.g. rhetoric.